# Using CSS-Grid Layout in Angular

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

I am fairly new to Angular (and SPA/Web development in general) and trying to get Angular working together with the new CSS-Grid layout.

Chances are I am simply not importing/injecting a required module but in any case cannot get this to work without getting errors. I did search but could not really find any guide or tutorial for this (Angular **and** CSS-Grid). There is some information about the CSS-Grid of course but close to nothing related to Angular.

I tried for example the following (taken from here http://maddesigns.de/css-grid-layout-2764.html):

```css
/* CSS */
.wrapper {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;   
}
```

```html
 <!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box a">.a</div>
   <div class="box b">.b</div>
   <div class="box c">.c</div>
   <div class="box d">.d</div>
 </div>
```

That snippet works here ('Run Code snippet').

But if I create a new angular/CLI project and copy the code straight to app.component.css and app.component.html (probably a bit naive) then it is kind of working but in Firefox I am also getting the error **"Error when processing the value 'display'. Declaration ignored."** (translated manually from German to English)

This makes me believe I am missing something fundamentally I am not aware of.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the css/html, you should add your angular's code as well.

Comment: I pasted that code as is to app.component.css and app.component.html

Comment: Consider overviewing: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: That did not help but the pointer was excellent never the less!

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2018/10/angular_directives_for_css3_grid

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, the issue turned out to be browser related which just shows how new I am to web development.

I tested some browsers:

- IE 11: does not work, exception
- Chrome 62: works, no warnings
- Firefox 56: works, but shows the warning mentioned in the question
- Firefox 57 (Quantum): works, no warnings

Comment: A great resource for things like this is CanIUse. For example [css-grid](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will helps for you;

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[v-grid]"
})
export class GridDirective {
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-columns")
  @Input() columns: string;
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-rows")
  @Input() rows: string;
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-areas")
  @Input() areas: string;

  constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef, private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "display", "grid");
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "height", "100%");
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: "[v-grid-area]"
})
export class GridAreaDirective {
  @HostBinding("style.grid-area")
  @Input("v-grid-area") area: string;
}
```

Using like this;

```
<div v-grid columns="1fr 100px" rows="1fr 1fr" areas="'area1 area2' 'area1 area2'">
   <div v-grid-area="area1" style="background-color: red">
      <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
   </div>
   <div v-grid-area="area2" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
</div>
```